# Open SharePoint 2013 panel in browser after creating a new Web Application with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have SharePoint 2013 on a local virtual machine and I created a local Web Application using that PowerShell script:

```
#This is the Web Application URL
$WebApplicationURL = "http://test.intranet.local";
#This is the Display Name for the SharePoint Web Application
$WebApplicationName = "Test";
#This is the Display Name for the Application Pool
$ApplicationPoolDisplayName = "TestApp Pool";
#This is identity of the Application Pool which will be used (Domain\User)
$ApplicationPoolIdentity = "domain\username";

if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) 
{
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}

$HostHeader = $WebApplicationURL.Substring(7)
$HTTPPort = "80"

$ContentDatabase = "Test ContentDatabase"

New-SPServiceApplicationPool -Name $ApplicationPoolDisplayName -Account $ApplicationPoolIdentity

$AppPool = (Get-SPServiceApplicationPool $ApplicationPoolDisplayName) 
$AppPoolManagedAccount = (Get-SPManagedAccount $ApplicationPoolIdentity | select username)

$ap = New-SPAuthenticationProvider
$WebApp = New-SPWebApplication -ApplicationPool $AppPool.Name -ApplicationPoolAccount $AppPoolManagedAccount.Username -Name $WebApplicationName -url $WebApplicationURL -port $HTTPPort -DatabaseName $ContentDatabase -HostHeader $hostHeader -AuthenticationProvider $ap
```

When I run the script everything works fine. After that I created the root site:

```
$template = Get-SPWebTemplate "STS#0";
$WebApplicationURL = "http://test.intranet.local";
$SiteCollectionURL= $WebApplicationURL+ "/"

$site = New-SPSite -Url $SiteCollectionURL -OwnerAlias "domain\username" -Template $template
```

When I try opening the SharePoint panel on Internet Explorer using the Web Application URL I can't display the page.
I'm a SharePoint newbie and I remember I faced this problem in the past and I resolved it adding the URL in a configuration file. Now I don't remember how I did that thing, could anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is a development/test machine, you need to DisableLoopbackCheck on your machine and add a host entry.

Steps are as below:

Open powershell and add the following command:

```
New-ItemProperty HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa -Name "DisableLoopbackCheck" -value "1" -PropertyType dword
```

If you want to do it manually,

1. go to Run > type regedit and then
   click OK
2. In Registry Editor, locate the following registry key:
       HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa
3. Right-click Lsa, point to New, and then click DWORD Value. (In Win
           2008, its DWORD 32bit)
4. Type DisableLoopbackCheck, and then press ENTER.
5. Right-click DisableLoopbackCheck, and then click Modify.
6. In the Value data box, type 1 and then click OK.
7. Quit Registry Editor.
8. You may need to restart your server.

After doing , that you need to add the entry in the hosts file as below:

1. Go to this path  `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\`
2. Open the hosts file
3. Add the entry as `127.0.0.1 test.intranet.local`
4. Restart browser
5. Open the site collection, you will get the authentication prompt.

Answer (score 0):

If this is not a development machine, you will need to add the URL to your DNS Server.